# What's the correct syntax for Regex in an Ecto Query?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Neither of these work:

`from m in Model, where: m.name == ^~r(/.*#{query}.*/i)`

`from m in Model, where: m.name =~ ^~r(/.*#{query}.*/i)`

What's the correct syntax? I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're trying to match a case insensitive phrase, you should use [`ilike/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#ilike/2) which uses the [SQL LIKE operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp):

```
from m in Model, where: ilike(m.name, "%#{query}%")
```

`like/2` would be used for a case sensitive search.

Ecto doesn't support regex out of the box because the implementations vary wildly between databases. What you'll need to do is look into the regular expression syntax for the database you're targeting and build that part of the query yourself using an Ecto [`fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1). The following example, which searches for all models that match `/^Peter [A-Z]$/`, uses [PostgreSQL's POSIX regex feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
from m in Model, where: fragment('? ~ ?', m.name, '^Peter [A-Z]$')
```